# Angular 6.x display value from callback

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

I am currently working on a component which displays a table. We have several input arguments including a `TableCellDefinition` which contains an `attributename`, `displayname` etc. and a callback function with the type `(e: Element) => string`. The idea was that you can provide a callback function with an anchor tag to the detail element.

While it is working perfectly fine for normal HTML, I would like to extend it to be useful with typescript code. I would like to add, let's say a `<mat-select>` to it and have it evaluated correctly.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with a TemlateRef that I'm injection into the component